# PHP LDAP: Error encountered on ldap_search

Tags: php, ldap

I got this piece of code in the internet and did some little modifications. I am planning to authenticate the user of my site by matching their inputted userid and password with our AD.

The code seems to work but when I try to add the mail attribute, i am getting this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: mail in C:\xampp\htdocs\ldap\index2.php on line 34
Retrieved 1 Active Directory users
```

Please help me find the error. I want to fetch the mail of the user and display it on screen.

```
<?php

$ldap_password = "mypassword";
$ldap_username = "myusername@domain";
$ldap_connection = ldap_connect("domain");
if (FALSE === $ldap_connection){
    echo "you are not connected to ldap server";
}

ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die('Unable to set LDAP protocol version');
ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

if (TRUE === ldap_bind($ldap_connection, $ldap_username, $ldap_password)){
    $ldap_base_dn = "DC=something,DC=something,DC=something";
    $search_filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(samaccountname=myusername))";
    $attributes = array();
    $attributes[] = "givenname";
    $attributes[] = "mail";
    $attributes[] = "samaccountname";
    $attributes[] = "sn";
    $result = ldap_search($ldap_connection, $ldap_base_dn, $search_filter, $attributes);
    if (FALSE !== $result){
        $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_connection, $result);
        for ($x=0; $x<$entries['count']; $x++){
            if (!empty($entries[$x]['givenname'][0]) || 
                !empty($entries[$x]['mail'][0]) || 
                !empty($entries[$x]['samaccountname'][0]) || 
                !empty($entries[$x]['sn'][0])
                ){
                $ad_users[strtoupper(trim($entries[$x]['samaccountname'][0]))] = array('email' => strtolower(trim($entries[$x]['mail'][0])),'first_name' => trim($entries[$x]['givenname'][0]),'last_name' => trim($entries[$x]['sn'][0]));
            }
        }
    }
    ldap_unbind($ldap_connection); 
}

echo "Retrieved ". count($ad_users) ." Active Directory users\n";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the Attribute is named `mail`? What do you get when you query the LDAP with a 'known-to-work-tool' like `ldapsearch`? On a *nix-like system you should be able to query the LDAP using this command:

```
ldapsearch -h domain -b DC=something,DC=something,DC=something "(&(objectCategory=person)(samaccountname=myusername))" givenname,mail,samaccountname,sn
```

Do you get the expected results? Does the result contain an entry for `mail`?

Alternately you can insert a `var_dump($entries[$x])` as the first item of the `for`-loop to see whether the `mail`-Attribute is set.

Hope that helps